# Using req.query in express with the request module

Tags: json, node.js, express, request

I am currently using Mikeal's request module in express. I am trying to get a bunch of data from two json urls and put them into a table. I want to be able to define two dates to use in the json url in **req.query** but I'm not too sure how. Right now, I'm able to define the dates in my terminal but I want to get rid of that. This is what I have so far.

```
var request = require('request);
var link = https://examplelink.json;
var args = process.argv.splice(2);
var date1 = args[0];
var date2 = args[1];
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    request.get({url: link + date1, json: true}, function(err, body, a) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(500);
        }
        request.get({url: link + date2, json: true}, function(err, body, b) {
            if (err) {
                 return res.send(500);
            }
            res.render('table' { a: a, b: b});
       });
}):

var number = 7000;
app.listen(number);
console.log("Listening at " + number);
```

This is a simplified version but I hope it gets the message across. I would like to modify this so that I don't have to define the dates with *args* and I can do it in the url.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the date arguments as query string parameters in the URL such as `http://localhost:7000?date1=2013-07-22&date2=2013-07-23`. To access these in express they will be `req.query.date1` and `req.query.date2` inside your `app.get('/'` handler function.